# Hostname not set when booting packer-created DigitalOcean image

Tags: debian, vagrant, digital-ocean, packer

I have a pretty simple config that generates an image from DigitalOcean's Debian 8 image:

```
{
  "builders": [
    {
      "type": "digitalocean",
      "image": "debian-8-x64",
      "region": "nyc3",
      "size": "512mb",
      "snapshot_name": "debian-8-x64-with-sudo-{{timestamp}}"
    }
  ],
  "provisioners": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "inline": [
        "apt-get update",
        "apt-get install -y sudo"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

When I launch the instance, running `hostname` provides:

packer-5694292c-afbf-6df6-06e2-304624c76287

running `hostname -f` results in this error message:

`hostname: Name or service not known`

However, looking in `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname` shows that the server should have the hostname I specified in my `Vagrantfile`:

`macmini-test-ae179a2c3b6a274e1c024fa3aee47b99cb234f5967a7c50b4db47119f4e1fda5`

How can I fix the `hostname -f` error to make the FQDN error go away? I can't figure out where the `packer-5694292c-afbf-6df6-06e2-304624c76287` hostname is on the system either. I know that's what packer used during building, but I'm not sure where it is on the system now.

Answer (score 1):

Vagrant is probably populating the /etc/hostname and /etc/hosts file, but something needs to run hostname -s to actually set it once the box is running:

```
root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~# echo coolhostyo > /etc/hostname
root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~# hostname
vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64
root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~#
```

Answer (score 1):

My hostname was invalid as it was too long. To quote wikipedia:

> Each label must be between 1 and 63 characters long

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname#Restrictions_on_valid_host_names